# Failed to connect Dart VM service to Windows subsystem for Android

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart, windows-subsystem-for-android

Since some days, I am unable to debug a Flutter app with Windows subsystem for Android properly.
Sometimes it works fine, but after a few minutes the debugger disconnect.

To connect on WSA I use:

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:58526
```

Those are the logs I get when I run and debug my app:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Subsystem for Android TM in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              7,5s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter ( 1706): Could not start Dart VM service HTTP server:
I/flutter ( 1706): SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Function not implemented, errno = 38), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 0
I/flutter ( 1706): #0      _NativeSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:996:7)
I/flutter ( 1706): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 1706): #1      Server.startup.startServer (dart:vmservice_io/vmservice_server.dart:430:19)
I/flutter ( 1706): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 1706): #2      Server.startup (dart:vmservice_io/vmservice_server.dart:449:11)
I/flutter ( 1706): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Once this error message appear, my app is launched but get stuck at splash screen (with Flutter icon)

The only solution I have is to restart the Subsystem for Android, then my app works for some minutes and the problem is back.

With React Native, a similar problem appear at the same time I had this problem with Flutter, the solution was to execute this command:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

It may be a change in the newest version of Subsystem for Android.

Answer (score 0):

After installing your app on the `VM`, go to `Standby apps` in the Developer Options and set it to `RESTRICTED` This will prevent the app from being kept alive this should do the trick.

If that didn't work, enable `Don't keep activities` and set the `Background process limit` to `No background processes`.

Answer (score 0):

By updating Windows subsystem for Android to the latest stable version, I no longer have this issue

WSA Version: 2303.40000.5.0 (Android 13)

Also I added a PATH system variable that might help:

Name: `NO_PROXY`
Value: `127.0.0.1`